# Why can't the type conversion of `this` be implicitly inferred from the generic contraint?

Tags: c#, generics, types, constraints, implicit

I have the following class:

```
public class Item<TItem>
    where TItem : Item<TItem>
{
    void GetReference()
    {
        TItem item = this;
    }
}
```

Here `TItem item = this;` generates a compiler error "can't convert `Item<TItem>` implicitly to `TItem`".

But why do we need a conversion here? We have defined the constraint `where TItem : Item<TItem>`, so one can think that no conversion is needed at all since the two types are the same, aren't they?

Btw an explicit conversion is available. This also is stated in the compiler error.

Comment: Why do you believe that the `where` clause describes *identity* of `TItem` with its constraint?  If you said `where TItem : Mammal` would you expect that `TItem` had to be *exactly mammal* or would you expect it to mean that `TItem` must be *any type that is compatible with `Mammal`*, like `Tiger` or `Dog`?  I am interested to know how people come to false beliefs about programming languages; what do you believe the `where` clause means, and how did you learn that?

Comment: I looked at it an thought: "Well, `TItem` can be `Item<TItem>` or anything derived from that. So since we are currently working in the class `Item<TItem>` this class (type of `this`) should fall into the category and as a consequence should be assignable to a `TItem`." 

With that the case Jon Skeet illustrated quietly slipped out of my mind.

Comment: Got it; thanks!  If this subject interests you, I wrote an article on it a few years back. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/  I recommend avoiding this pattern; as you have discovered, it is hard to reason about.

Comment: I've read my comment now a couple of times and now the mistake I made got clearer to me. Still it's hard to get some training on this concept since it's hard to visualize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it wouldn't be safe. Consider:

```
public class GoodItem : Item<GoodItem>
{
    // No problem
}

public class EvilItem : Item<GoodItem>
{
    // GetReference body would be equivalent to 
    // GoodItem item = this;
    // ... but this *isn't* a GoodItem, it's an EvilItem!
}
```

`EvilItem` satisfies the constraint for `TItem` with no problems - `GoodItem` is indeed derived from `Item<GoodItem>`.

There's no way of expressing a relationship between the *class being declared* and a type parameter, which is what you really want.

Answer (score 3):

That's because your class is type `Item<TItem>` not `TItem`. You could have;

```
Item<TItem> item = this;
```

The sample is a bit of a mind bender. To put this into context `TItem item = this;` resolves to trying to do

```
Item<TItem> item = new Item<Item<TItem>>();
```

Comment: But `TItem` has to be `Item<TItem>` right? Since the contraint is telling it

Comment: @BrunoZell I think you're getting mixed up with what the generic is saying. If you want an instance of `TItem`, you could have `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TItem))` but the class is it's own type, *with* a generic of type `TItem` but isn't itself `TItem`. It's `Item<TItem>`

Comment: @DiskJunky he is doing the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), The generic constraint says *"`TItem` must be or inherit from `Item<TItem>`"*, `this` is a `Item<TItem>` so therefor it should be assignable.

Comment: `TItem item = this as TItem` would be valid though. Why does I need to explicitly state it?
Edit: `TItem item = (TItem)this` is valid too

Comment: @BrunoZell You can cast anything to anything and it will compile.  That's just deferring the problem to runtime.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that may be the pattern but `Item<TItem>` is certainly not the same as `TItem`. It's like trying to assign `IEnumerable<int>` to `int`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The constraint says that `TItem` is convertible to `Item<TItem>`, it *doesn't* say that `Item<TItem>` is convertible to `TItem`.  Just imagine if the constraint said `where TItem : object`.  Just because you know `TItem` is an object doesn't mean all objects are `TItem`s.

Comment: @Servy, in context of the code example, this would be trying to assign `Item<Item<TItem>>` to `Item<TItem>`

Comment: @Servy it just clicked in my head. I get it now.

Answer (score 2):

because every `TItem` is `Item<TItem>` (as declared by where constraint), but not vice versa.

`TItem` could be more derived than `Item<TItem>`, so do `this`, `TItem` could be Apple and `this` could be oranges. so assignment is prevented by compiler.

currently in c# there is no way to declare that type parameter must match type of inheriting class itself.

there are two common ways to fix this. first use explicit cast

```
TItem GetReference() => (TItem) this;
```

Its your job to make sure inheriting class is using right type parameter, other wise you may get runtime exception if you ever try to use this method.

second way is to use return type of class itself. which is safe (no runtime exception) but does not have any sort of contract for derived classes. i.e you should make sure you write this method for every derived class.

```
Item<TItem> GetReference() => this;
```

now you can hide this method in derived classes.

```
new Derived GetReference() => this; // public class Derived : Item<Derived>
```

Note that this feature is already requested in GitHub c# repo, https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/252

you just have to wait for c# team to add this feature :)